# pandas convert a category to numerical for a string as a one object but got an array of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to factorize a column of dataframe in pandas and add it as a new column. The value of the column is a string.

e.g.

```
 COL_1
 'TRY A TEST'
 'TRY A TEST' 
 'PLAY Q'
 'PLAY Q'
```

I want it to be converted to numerical like:

```
 COL_1     NEW_COL
 'TRY A TEST'   0
 'TRY A TEST'   0
 'PLAY Q'       1
 'PLAY Q'       1
```

But, I got :

```
 x = 'TRY A TEST'
 my_df['NEW_COL'] = my_df['COL_1'].apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])

 (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64), array(['TRY A TEST'], dtype=object))
```

It seems that each char is converted to a number.

I also got error:

```
 TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

There is no float in "COL_1" and it is string.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
my_df['NEW_COL'] = le.fit_transform(my_df['COL_1'].astype(str))
my_df

        COL_1  NEW_COL
0  TRY A TEST        1
1  TRY A TEST        1
2      PLAY Q        0
3      PLAY Q        0
```

For large dataframe/ multiple columns you can simply use for loop

Eg.

```
my_df

     pets     owner   location
0     cat     Champ  San_Diego
1     dog       Ron   New_York
2     cat     Brick   New_York
3  monkey     Champ  San_Diego
4     dog  Veronica  San_Diego
5     dog       Ron   New_York

############
for column in ['pets','owner','location']:
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    my_df[str(column+'_num')] = le.fit_transform(my_df[column].astype(str))
############


my_df

     pets     owner   location  pets_num  owner_num  location_num
0     cat     Champ  San_Diego         0          1             1
1     dog       Ron   New_York         1          2             0
2     cat     Brick   New_York         0          0             0
3  monkey     Champ  San_Diego         2          1             1
4     dog  Veronica  San_Diego         1          3             1
5     dog       Ron   New_York         1          2             0
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative method, use [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) dtype:

```
my_df['NEW_COL'] = my_df['COL_1'].astype('category').cat.codes
```